# What is the best move in this puzzle rush?

Tags: analysis, puzzles

```
[FEN "2b2r1r/2k1q1b1/2p1p2p/1p1pPp2/pP1P1RB1/P1N5/2P1Q1PP/5RK1 w - f6 0 1"]
[starpPly "2"]

1. Bh5?
```

In this puzzle rush from chess.com, it says that Bh5 is the wrong move, although Stockfish shows it as the best. So what is the best possible move? It's the  17th puzzle and it is rated at 1124 ELO.

Comment: Uhm, did the Bh5 stand on g4 as I would guess from the diagram? I would always consider a sac on b5, but at the moment it is too thin, you need a rook on the third and with a Bg4 it can't work at all.

Comment: I've put the position with the Bishop on g4 into stockfish and left it on my machine for 40 minutes. Bh5 is the best move. I "hinted" by trying Nxb5, Nxd5, Nxa5 and Bxf5. Nothing good turns up. All I can think to ask is "are you sure the above position is correct?"

Comment: Hmm. Using the replayer instead of the static image implicitly involves making an assumption about the initial FEN.

Answer (score 24):

Did black just play f5 before? Then the right move is exf6 en passant, Bxf6 Rxf6 Rxf6 Qe5+ and win the piece.

```
[FEN "2b2r1r/2k1qpb1/2p1p2p/1p1pP3/pP1P1RB1/P1N5/2P1Q1PP/5RK1 b - - 1 1"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[StartPly "3"]

1... f5 2. exf6 Bxf6 3. Rxf6 Rxf6 4. Qe5+
```

Comment: AHHHHH! Take an upvote!

Comment: Good grief. I expect such a "stinker" in a problem but not in a tactics puzzle. (Although, the puzzle should come with a FEN and that should show it's legal, so *theoretically* you can find out?!)

Comment: Puzzle rush shows the previous move being played, and highlights the from/to squares of the moved piece as well. So it's just as obvious whether en passant is legal as in a normal game.